# Wordpress Saving Multiple select items error

Tags: wordpress, save, metadata, custom-post-type

i created a meta box with a select item tha takes its value from another post.
I tried many methods of update but don't work....can you help me?

this is my box

```
add_action("add_meta_boxes", "palinsesto_box");

function palinsesto_box() {
add_meta_box("palinsesto-meta", "Speakers",   "palinsesto_manager_meta_options", "palinsesto",   "side");}

function palinsesto_manager_meta_options($post)
{
wp_nonce_field( 'radio_schedule', 'schedule_noncename' );
echo '<label for="speaker_id">';
_e("Speaker", 'speaker_id' );
echo '</label> ';
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'speaker');
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
echo '<select name="speaker_id" id="speaker_id" multiple="multiple">';
foreach($loop->posts as $dj):
    if($dj->ID == get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'speaker_id', true ))
    {
        $select = 'selected';
    }else{
    $select = '';
}
echo '<option value="'.$dj->ID.'" '.$select.'>'.$dj->post_title.'</option>';
endforeach;
echo '</select>';
echo '<p>Tieni premuto CTRL per selezionare più speakers</p>';
}

add_action('save_post', 'save_palinsesto_manager_meta_options');
function save_palinsesto_manager_meta_options($post_id)
{global $post;
if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ){
    //if you remove this the sky will fall on your head.
    return;
}else{
    update_post_meta($post->ID, 'speaker_id', implode( ',', $_POST['speaker_id']));
}
}
```

i update the wrongest update function too....help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if( isset( $_POST['speaker_id'] ) ) {  
    update_post_meta( $post_id,'speaker_id', esc_attr( $_POST['speaker_id'] ) );  
}
```

I found the solution but it save only one value and not multiple....how can I do?